# Один и тот же APK файл работает по разному на эмуляторе и телефон

Tags: java, android-studio, apk

Я создал в Adroid Studio app-release.apk через меню Build. Запускаю этот файл на эмуляторе Nox - всё работает правильно и показывает все последние изменения. А когда я запускаю тот же самый файл на своём телефоне - он запускает старое приложение, в котором нет изменений.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё раз привет. Если ты не нашёл решения задачи так вот: (Я вчера тоже с ней столкнулся)

Перестанови эмулятор если это возможно и удали старую версию апк файла, потом собери снова и протестируй на телефоне, лично такая последовательность действий дала мне тот результат который я хотел увидеть. Я редко пользуюсь эмулятор и то в основном что бы подогнать по стандартам других телефонов.